# Parsing an online CSV files with Xcode for an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, string, csv

I am trying to parse an CSV file which is stored online on my server.

http://idoodler.de/liftinfo.csv

I like to put every String in to an label but I don't know how to parse an CSV file. I searched the web but no solution helped me. Please help me, if you know a solution please explain it to me with sorcecode because parsing CSV files is new for me. Thanks a lot!!

I now know I should use [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) but I don't know how to use it, I don't know how to get the strings from the CSV file. Does anyone know?

OK, I now have this code:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.idoodler.de/liftinfo.csv"]];
    NSString *csvResponseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"String: %@",csvResponseString);
```

But I'm always getting this: `String: (null)`

So Dies anyone know a solution to get the String instead of the (null)?

Comment: take a look to this article http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "parsing" and not "phrasing", in this case you can try this https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: Thank you for your answer but isn't there an easier method?

Comment: I suggest that you use this or similar class to parse csv, it can become really tricky with csv and you will have to look to a lot of things. You have to just add the .h and .m of a single class to your project, trust me this method is easy.

Comment: How do I set the URL to the CSV file? And how do I get the Strings? I can't find an answer in the ReadMe of the project.

Comment: The author of CHCSVParser is an active member of stackoverflow, Dave Delong. Try to search for it on stackoverflow and you will find a lot of examples and explanations. Basically you have to download the file into a string and use the parser on that string.

Answer (score 2):

I finally made it, but without the CHCSVParser. I just used this code:

```
//From File URL get entire CSV as NSstring 
NSString *absoluteURL = @"Put your URL here!!";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:absoluteURL];
NSString *fileString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSArray *contentArray = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];     
for (NSString *item in contentArray) {
    NSArray *itemArray = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    NSLog(@"String -----> %@",[itemArray objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```